# Word for using software without knowing how it works

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am looking for single word or set of few words for the following meaning:

Using software (for example calculating mean of 10 given numbers) without knowing the details how the software internally works for computing the things (for example mean of 10 given numbers).

Comment: I am looking for more common word used in speaking with negative sense

Comment: I am looking for the word to communicate with the people who knows little English.

Comment: Welcome to ELU :-). I think that blackbox is a great word, but if you are set in your opinion that it wouldn't work for you, you can always edit your question to explain which options have you cast out and why - this would help people who are trying to answer. You might also consider our sister site: [English language learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) in the future - regardless of your fluency if you are asking how to communicate something to a person with poor English language skills, the question should be on topic there :-). Just please don't double post this question.

Comment: Please don't post answers in the comments.

Comment: If you can edit and write a sentence where you want to use it, it may help people to find an answer ;)

Comment: A user is **not** expected to "know the details (of) how the software internally works" -- NARQ.

Comment: Oddball ('I only drive it. I don't know how it works.')

Comment: This is utter and complete nonsense!!  Aside, perhaps, from the software on tiny microprocessors, ***no one***, not even the most skilled programmer, knows how the software they are using works.

Answer (score 5):

The meme [I Have No Idea What I'm Doing](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-have-no-idea-what-im-doing) may fit in your case.

[image]

---

I posted this because it came to my mind but [abstraction from Tushar answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255144/word-for-using-software-without-knowing-how-it-works/255156#answer-255150) must be what you are looking for.

Comment: yes, yes I was looking for the word for the same sense. But it is too much! I want little softer word!

Comment: @jean I know ;) As I indicated, Tushar answered well about this with *"abstraction"*

Comment: Haha. Just saw this. +1.

Answer (score 5):

[image]
<sub>*image generated by [relikemindia.com](http://relikemindia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Turnkey-project.jpg)*</sub>

The word that comes to my mind is *[turnkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Turnkey)*:

> Turnkey refers to something that is ready for immediate use, generally
>   used in the sale or supply of goods or services. The word is a
>   reference to the fact that the customer, upon receiving the product,
>   just needs to turn the ignition key to make it operational.

Although it generally refers to the product or service, *turnkey* can be easily applied to the usage:

> *The end user will enjoy the **turnkey** operation of our software product.*

Answer (score 4):

The technical word for hiding details of workings is **[abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science))**

> In computer science, abstraction is a technique for managing complexity of computer systems. It works by establishing a level of complexity on which a person interacts with the system, suppressing the more complex details below the current level. <sub>(Wikipedia)</sub>

A user interface (UI) allows users to interact with the abstracted software.

---

EDIT: Using software without knowing how it works is the way it's supposed to be used. It is not a separate subset warranting a new word. A user who *does* know how it works is the exception; not the rule.

Almost everything around us, from cars to elevators to coffee machines, is supposed to be *used* by interacting on an abstracted level. The nitty-gritty of how it actually works are generally known only by the people who create it (developers, in your case).

So, the verb you're looking for is ***`using`***. The noun, which developers employ for people who use it without knowing how it works, is ***`users`***.

Comment: nope, let's say how if someone is using something with out knowing in detail about it.

Comment: @Jean: You are using the UI on an abstracted level of complexity. It's like stepping on the brake pedal without actually knowing what goes on inside the car to slow it down.

Comment: Not necessarily '[u]sing software without knowing the details how the software internally works'. Some programmers may understand the inner workings.

Comment: *Abstraction* is the other end of the dynamic the OP inquires about: setting up a program so that the user can use it without knowing how it works.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You may *understand* but you are not *bothered by the complexity*. And abstraction describe it well. (Tushar you have my +1)

Comment: Abstraction is the case when the developer does not want you to know that information. (eg- source code for some software).

The OP however refers to the case where the user should have some vague idea of how the program works. 

Example- If in a calculator program, I type 2+2, I already know the result will be 4 because I know how the software works;
but I do not know the source behind it (num1.getText +num2.getText) sort of stuff or even if its written in C or java or something else..

Comment: I agree with the comment from @Invoker

Comment: @YohannV.: Thank you. Good to see that someone gets my point.

Comment: @ScotM: I agree. However, I don't think there's a common word for the OP's end.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Point taken. Edited to clarify.

Comment: @Invoker **Abstraction** is about : `The act of focusing on one characteristic of an object rather than the object as a whole group of characteristics`. i.e. focusing on **how to use** a software and do not pay attention to **how it works**. Having a vague knowledge about the basic operations inside is *irrelevant*.

Comment: @TusharRaj with the comment I made, I am not sure you underline better your point about *abstraction* by using its technical computer meaning since jean need a basic word. (I still think it is the right word but a common def would have served you better imho)

Comment: @YohannV: A common def of abstraction, you mean? Should I include it?

Comment: @ The [OED defs](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abstraction) don't seem to fit. If you have one fom another source that does, feel free to edit and add. Or post the link in a comment.

Comment: @TusharRaj I'm not invisible ! The 4th def is close but, even if its usage is highly discouraged, I like the [third wiki def](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abstraction).

Answer (score 0):

The word that immediately comes to mind would be :

> Script Kiddie.

And although the word is traditionally associated with using softwares written by others to attack a computer/network of computers;

It can be, however, used to describe the person you mentioned in a much broader sense, that is not just tools like *nmap* but other genres as well.

Defination from wikipedia :

> In programming culture a script kiddie or skiddie (also known as skid, script bunny, script kitty) is an unskilled individual who uses scripts or programs developed by others to attack computer systems and networks, and deface websites.

Answer (score 0):

How about "**automatic**", or, if the user is very primitive: ***"It's magic!"***

Answer (score 0):

How about "They are using the software without knowing how it works."

Comment: yes, I am looking for single word or slang for it.

Comment: Since 99.9% of people do not have a clue how the software's internals work, there's no special word for it. It's called "using the software" and they are called "end-users".  When *programmers*  (or engineers) use a program or a device, without having access to its internals, they refer to it as a "black box".

Comment: @jean - the are called  *software users*

Comment: @Josh61 yes formally...

Comment: @jean: the slang word you seek does not exist.

Comment: @jean -  you could do  with *software illiterate*

Comment: @josh61:  That means someone who doesn't know how to use software, doesn't it?   You wouldn't call a CFO Excel wizard "software illiterate" if he didn't know how the internals worked, would you?

Comment: @TimRomano - I am not sure, I think it can work both ways.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8694874/449347 uses three terms : -

- Abstraction
- Information Hiding
- Encapsulation.

Other answers have focused on abstraction, but I think the other two may be more relevant to OP.

Quoting the summary

> ... are very different, but highly-related, concepts. One could argue that **abstraction** is a technique that help us identify which specific information should be visible, and which information should be hidden. **Encapsulation** is then the technique for packaging the information in such a way as to **hide** what should be hidden, and make visible what is intended to be visible."

Or to put it another [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24748/449347)

> encapsulation is most often achieved through information hiding, which is the process of hiding all of the secrets of object that do not contribute to its essential characteristics. — Grady Booch